# 'Chrono' file not found time.h import firestore using cocoapod in Swift 5 / IOS 10

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swift5

We are on Swift 5, IOS 10. We recently included Firesbase/Firestore in the pod file. The pod file looks like this.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.4'

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'              # Used to upload files with multipart
pod 'MessageKit', '~> 3.0.0-swift5'


end
```

When we build the project, .

```
import FirebaseFirestore
```

we get the following error

```
'chrono' file not found time.h
```

Tried all the suggestions listed [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1610). But none seem to work.

Comment: Any success solving this issue?